# Maximum PID in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pid

I am porting an application from Tru64 to Linux and it uses PID_MAX defined in limits.h.
Linux doesn't have that define. 
How do I find PID_MAX in **c** without reading `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` by hand?
Is there a library?

Comment: AFAIK, PID_MAX in Linux is UINT_MAX, which depends on the cpu

Comment: `UINT_MAX` does not depend on the CPU in Linux. It's always 0x7fffffff.

Comment: Erm, I meant `INT_MAX`. `pid_t` is of course a signed int, not unsigned, but I mentally copied what gnif wrote. :-)

Comment: `PID_MAX_LIMIT` is defined in `threads.h`. See https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/threads.h#L33.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

It's 32768 by default, you can read the value on your system in `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max`.

And you can set the value higher on 64-bit systems (up to 2<sup>22</sup> = 4,194,304) with:

```
echo 4194304 > /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
```

Read more here:

[http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/condorg/linux_scalability.html (via archive.org)](http://web.archive.org/web/20111209081734/http://research.cs.wisc.edu/condor/condorg/linux_scalability.html)

Comment: Ok that was not what I wanted to do but I ended up reading the value from the file. I guess there is no other way.

Comment: The Condor link in your answer went 404, unfortunately. I've replaced it with a link through archive.org, of course it'd be better if you know of a current version of the document.

Comment: Is the limit shown in that `pid_max` file inclusive? Can `getpid()` return that very number or is the maximum that number minus one? (i.e. by default, can a process have PID 32768 or is the maximum 32767?)

Comment: Nice, for `Ubuntu 20.04` it looks like `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` is now set to `4194304`...

Answer (score 21):

The maximum value of the PID in Linux is configurable. You can access it trough `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` file. This file (new in Linux 2.5) specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e., the value in this file is one greater than the maximum PID). The default value for this file, 32768, results in the same range of PIDs as on earlier kernels. The value in this file can be set to any value up to 2^22 (PID_MAX_LIMIT, approximately 4 million).

From the programming perspective, you have to use `pid_t` type to work with process ID. You can even access its min/max values using integer traits. Here is an example of doing that using C++ and Boost on Linux 2.6.X running on x86_64 platform:

```
$ cat test.cpp 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/integer_traits.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "pid_t max = " << boost::integer_traits<pid_t>::const_max << endl;
}

$ ./test 
pid_t max = 2147483647
```

Comment: Question is tagged C, not C++. The second half of your answer does not apply to C and is not possible in C.

Comment: @R: This is just an example, if I knew how to get compile-time traits for pid_t in C, I'd write C. I am sure there is some equivalent with macros.

Comment: @yuyichao it would be more like `pow(8, sizeof(pid_t))`.

Comment: @bfontaine you are right, the first one is wrong, (pid_t)-1 should work though and is computed at compile time.

Comment: @yuyichao `pid_t` is signed, and functions like `getpid` return -1 to indicate an error. The maximum value can be found with a macro as described in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053843/min-and-max-value-of-data-type-in-c - for example `(pid_t)((1LLU<<((sizeof(pid_t)*8)-1))-1LLU)` is `2147483647` on my machine.

Comment: @bfontaine it would be more like `pow(2, 8 * sizeof(pid_t))`. (not a perfect solution, but I wanted to clear up the glaring error with raising 8 to the number bytes, which is barely even related to the desired value)

Comment: @craig65535 getpid is guaranteed not to return an error

Comment: not only does it not work in C, in C++ it gives the wrong answer. (too high)

Answer (score 14):

From the `proc(5)` man page:

> `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` (since Linux 2.5.34)
>
> This file specifies the value at which PIDs wrap around (i.e., the value in this file is one greater than the  maximum  PID). PIDs greater than this value are not allocated; thus, the value in this file also acts as a system-wide limit on the total number of processes and threads.  The default value for this file, 32768,  results  in  the  same range  of  PIDs as on earlier kernels.  On 32-bit platforms, 32768 is the maximum value for pid_max.  On 64-bit systems, `pid_max` can be set to any value up to 2^22 (`PID_MAX_LIMIT`, approximately 4 million).

Comment: I'm glad that you included reference.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Ubuntu 20.04 has pushed the limit to the maximum (4194304):

```
% cat /proc/sys/kernel/pid_max
4194304
```

Comment: for me it's 32768 (Ubuntu 20.04 WSL2)

Comment: @MaasoudAsadi interesting, I guess it might be because WSL2 might have another kernel...

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 and 4194304 here.

Comment: Same for Ubuntu 22.04. I was curious since top reports PIDs well beyond 32768