# Process management in C++

Tags: c++, bash, process, debian

I am developing my application in C, and when application starts it needs to kill shell script which runs from system startup.

Here is my function that kills shell script from C++:

```
void Kill_Script_sh(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[30];
    char pid_number[5];
    int pid;
    int fd;
    std::stringstream command;

    command.str("");
    fp = popen("ps aux | grep tick.sh", "r");

    fgets(buffer, 30, fp);

    pclose(fp);

    pid_number[0] = buffer[11];
    pid_number[1] = buffer[12];
    pid_number[2] = buffer[13];
    pid_number[3] = buffer[14];
    pid_number[4] = buffer[15];


    pid = atoi(pid_number);

    printf("%d \n", pid);

    command << "sudo kill " << pid;

    system(command.str().c_str());
}
```

After I killed the process I need to check if it still exists. Is this correct way to do what I need? Any idea is helpful. Thanks

Comment: That's not C, that's C++.

Comment: Have you tried your `ps` command line ? Chances are that your `grep` is matched as well, resulting in your killing the `grep` instead of the script.

Comment: @molbdnilo it is mixed.

Comment: @Zola There's no such thing. It's either one or the other.

Comment: @molbdnilo there is, because this is an app for embedded systems, it is compiled with g++ and everything is okay.

Comment: You are using 4 digits for the PID. Are you sure it's a good idea? [Under Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294133/maximum-pid-in-linux) the default maximum PID is 32768. **If you forget one digit you will kill the wrong process!!**

Comment: @FabioTurati I am aware of that, but this situation with parsing ps aux is little shaky, thats the reason I asked for ideas to do this on the other way.

Comment: Have you considered using a PID file? (i.e, a file containing your script's PID, preferably with a `flock` held for the duration)

Comment: I'm finding the PID number of my process correctly, only problem is checking if its still alive. @Hasturkun

Comment: There is only one way under standard UNIX to safely check if a child process ended, and that is by letting it's **parent** test this! Any other approch ends up in a race for PIDs. Do you have by any means the possibility to adjust/add the/a process spawing `wdt_tick.sh`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After killing it (or in general), you can check for existence of a process using `kill -0 [pid]`.

Comment: Your answer is correct only for the "*in general*" case, as you cannot do this safely, as there might very well be another process having been spawned with this very PID while the "original" process" ended.