# Maximum PID on osx

Tags: macos, pid

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294133/maximum-pid-in-linux/6294210#6294210) about what's the maximum PID for Linux and my question is exactly the same for OSX :

OSX doesn't seem to have the `/proc/sys/kernel/pid_max` file containing this value on Linux.

**Is there an equivalent file or an other way to find out what is the range of PIDs on an OSX system?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The maximum PID on macOS is 99998.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51119/whats-the-maximum-pid-for-mac-os-x)

Unlike on Linux, this value is not tunable. I'm not aware of any way to retrieve it in a program; the only assumption you should make is that the value of a process ID will fit into the `pid_t` type.