# Why does it return a null pointer when I try to visit the status file of a task?

Tags: c, ubuntu, process, operating-system

I was programming with C language to get some information of the processes and tasks on Ubuntu(Ubuntu 20.04 and gcc 9.3.0).
I used the following code to scan the directory of the task of a process with a known pid:

```c
char root_path[20] = "/proc/";
strcat(root_path, name_list[i]->d_name);
strcat(root_path, "/task");
tnum = scandir(root_path, &task_list, filter, alphasort);
```

where `name_list[i]->d_name` is the pid of the process in the form of char*.
Then I used the result in task_list to visit the status of those tasks:

```c
char path1[20] = "/proc/";
strcat(path1, task_list[j]->d_name);
strcat(path1, "/status");
FILE *fp = fopen(path1, "r");
```

It's just simple code. The problem I came cross is that although most of the tasks can be visited normally, there existed some task id that made fopen **return a null pointer fp**. I used assert statement to detect that. But when I use `cat /proc/tid/status` to check the file, it's there and could be normally accessed.
When I changed the directory into `/proc/pid/task/tid/status`, the problem still existed.
I want to know why I can't visit the certain task file, there seems no difference between it and other status files. The tid of the task that returns a null pointer is fixed until I compile the source code another time.

Comment: If `fopen` returns NULL, use `perror` to print an error message stating *why* the call failed.

Comment: You can replace `strcat(); strcat();` with `snprintf();`

Comment: You probably need to check the `errno` value to find the error cause. You can do it by `if (fp == NULL) printf("Error: %s\n", strerror(errno));`. Make sure you `#include` the `<string.h>` for `strerror` and `<errno.h>` for `errno` variable (it's actually a macro).

Comment: "I used assert statement to detect that." Note that `assert` should be used for debugging, not for error detection.

Comment: @IanAbbott: It's sure better than "segmentation fault" when you don't know why or even where.

Comment: @Joshua Yes, but it doesn't obviate the need to add proper error checking/handling.

Answer (score 0):

`char path1[20]` is too short. With these strings you need at least `char path1[24]` for the worst case sized PID. Your program is undefined due to running off the end of a stack array.

Once it's not undefined, if it keeps happening, call `perror(path1)` to print out the path you tried to access and the error message.

Hint: `sizeof("string")` can be used in the array declaration, so you could write `char path1[sizeof("/proc/" + 10 + sizeof("/status")]` and have the compiler do the counting for you.

Comment: pids are at most 5 digits on linux, so the longest these names could be is 19 characters (including the terminating NUL).

Comment: @ChrisDodd: I wouldn't be too sure about that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6294196/14768 shows you can set it to 7 digits today; thus 21 needed already.