# Max_Int reached before the limit defined in climits.h

Tags: max, limits

I get this error

[image: Error]

whenever I enter whatever number bigger than the following, in a code compiled with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express:

```
int size = 276447232;
```

Though, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271076/what-is-the-difference-between-an-int-and-a-long-in-c/271132#271132) [conversation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/size-of-int-long-etc), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329777/is-long-guaranteed-to-be-at-least-32-bits) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053843/min-and-max-value-of-data-type-in-c) [one](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/climits/), I should be able to go up to 2147483646 before encountering any problem, no?

Sky

Comment: I don't think that assignment will cause the `abort()` .. how is the variable/value being used? That is, is there a *different* line that actually triggers the "Debug Error!"?

Comment: Hi pst, sorry for the delay. Indeed, I use this `size` in the next line: 
`char *outputGwb=new char[size];`.

But the thing is that this error only appears when I change the `size` parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is trying to allocate too much *stack* space:

```
char *outputGwb = char[size]; // array is created "on the stack"
```

Use `malloc` (or `new` in C++) to allocate memory from the *heap*. Make sure to `free` (or `delete` in C++) the memory later; just don't mix the allocation/deallocation strategies.

```
char* outputGwb = new char[size]; // C++: note use of the "new" keyword
char* outputGwb = malloc(size);   // C:   note no cast needed in a C compiler
```

This issue is thus about the maximum size of a particular resource and is *not* related to the maximum number an integer value can represent.

See [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for an explanation between the two memory allocation areas. In addition, while I wouldn't necessarily recommend it, here is a [thread that discusses how to change the stack size in Visual C++](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/2a5b32b6-683b-4729-92d3-45ed7a89ef3f).

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to mention that I `delete` the memory later in the code. 


Though, I don't exactly get the change that it'd make: what is difference between _on the stack_ and _from the heap_?

Comment: @RobinLen'hog It's very bad to delete (or free) something that was not new'd (or malloc'ed) :) I have updated the post with a link to a question talking about stack vs heap and added examples of heap allocation in C and C++.

Comment: Thank you very much. To be clearer than I might have before in this post, I have the 3 lines present in my program : `int size = 276447232;`, `char *outputGwb=new char[size];`, and `delete [] outputGwb;` with the rest of my code in between the `new` and `delete` lines. I'm gonna take a look at the links and examples, thx again

Comment: After having browsed the links you gave me, I understand that I have asked for an allocation _from the heap_ (I already use `new`, that is why I `delete` at the end of my code). But when I go back to your answer I now read that you think that I "allocate too much _stack_ space". Is the _stack space_ directly related to allocating _from the heap_ or am I missing something? Thanks again

Comment: @RobinLen'hog I missed that .. I thought I saw it was without the `new`. In any case, it appears to be an allocation that fails, although ~280MB isn't "that big".