# Maximum Value for Unsigned Int is it -1

Tags: c, types, unsigned, unsigned-integer, unsigned-long-long-int

I was trying to figure out the minimum and maximum value for an unsigned data type. I know that the minimum unsigned value is 0 and the maximum value is (2^n)-1. However, when I tried to run my program (*I cannot post my code, but you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053843/min-and-max-value-of-data-type-in-c)*), I keep getting -1 as the maximum value. Can someone explain to me why? Also, UINT_MAX is giving me 4294967295 while ULLONG_MAX is 4294967295. However, the maximum value of unsigned int is supposed to be 65535 while unsigned long long int is supposed to be +18,446,744,073,709,551,615.Why is it the output is different?

Comment: Maybe you are printing it with wrong format specifier?

Comment: UINT_MAX is the same bit-wise as -1 in two's complement notation.  You're probably printing it out as a signed integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whats the format specifier are you using to print those values ?
These kind of error mostly occur due to wrong format specifier.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{  
    printf("%u", UINT_MAX); // This will print 4294967295 (system dependent)
    printf("%d", UINT_MAX); // This will print -1
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d", UINT_MAX); // This will print -1` This is also system dependent as not every system is two's complement.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: While in theory non-twos-complement machines can exist, you won't find one outside a museum.

Comment: I agree with both of your comment

Comment: the `%d` ver is undefined behaviour so could print anything , or format your hard drive

Comment: My classmates are also getting -1