# How are the datatype size limits in limits.h determined?

Tags: c, types

How are the size limits for data types in C determined?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053843/min-and-max-value-of-data-type-in-c)'s answers says to use `limits.h` for minimum and maximum values for datatypes. Although some people might stop at that and say ok, fine, I'm thinking: how does it know? How are the limits in `limits.h` set such that you can use that same `limits.h` on any machine (any environment?).

Obviously, a 32 bit machine handles things differently than a 64 bit machine. Then you've got your little endian versus big endian layer of complication. How does it know (in plain English)?

Comment: it's just hardcoded in compiler headers for each compiler version/platform

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre So somebody's job is to fill in those fields? “Hey, I wanna make a compiler for this processor”...then I have to call the company who made the processor and get the specifications, then derive may values from that? Is that how it works?

Comment: when the compiler is built/generated, the build scripts also create/generate/instanciate the limits.h header, because they know exactly which CPU it's targetting (with conditional #define, you can have a limits.h file for several architectures). And yes, to create a compiler for a CPU, you have to know exactly the CPU specs :)

Comment: creating a compiler is tough. That's why everyone doesn't create their own and rely on existing ones :)

Comment: It is not "that same limits.h". While the name is same, the content is not. For each environment the compiler has to provide the matching limits.h.

Comment: "then I have to call the company who made the processor and get the specifications" Yes. And you also want to ask for the number and names of registers, calling conventions (ABI), instruction set of the CPU and a lot more details. The values for limits.h are only a tiny part of that.

Comment: No need to call the company. You just need to read the spec of the processor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the C standard sets the minimum requirements. `int` must for example be large enough to at least hold the values -32767 to 32767. But the standard sets no upper limits for the compiler to use.

Then from there, whoever ports the compiler to a given system has to implement `limits.h` (and also `stdint.h`) to suit that compiler for the given system.

The size of `int` is traditionally set to the data bus width of the CPU, or rather to the largest possible size that the CPU can handle in a single instruction. But this is no requirement - for 64 bit CPUs, compilers kept `int` as 32 bit but instead let `long` or `long long` be the 64 bit type.

Also, the signedness format matters. The vast majority of real-world computers use 2's complement, and so the lower limit for a 16 bit type on a 2's complement system is  -32768 rather than -32767 as the minimum requirement by the standard. This is because the standard accepts some other wildly exotic signedness formats.

Endianess does however not apply here, as these headers are only concerned with variable sizes and not addressing of individual bytes.

Comment: Good eye. All the times I've picked through the standard, I never noticed the `-32768` and `-32767` minimum difference between a two's-compliment implementation and the standard. (frankly, I'd never thought about it either `:)`